# can not get element by id using jquery and d3 but working by native code

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

console log is below.

**-> d3.select("#node1")**

<- qa {_groups: Array[1], _parents: Array[1]}

**-> d3.select("#node1.1")**

<- Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#node1.1' is not a valid selector.(…)

**-> $("#node1")**

<- [​sdsdg​​]

**->  $("#node1.1")**

<- []

**-> document.getElementById("node1")**

<- ​sdsdg​​

**-> document.getElementById("node1.1")**

<- ​asfas​​

element #node1 has nothing problem. #node1.1 is working well by native javascript but jquery(3.0.0) and d3(4.1.1)

I don't know why. could I know what happened to #node1.1?

I could copy element selector by chrome developer tool. the result is

> element #node1 -> #node1
>
> element #node1.1 -> #node1\2e 1

Comment: Do people even read the error messages? "#node1.1' is not a valid selector.(…)" clearly points the problem out.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` character is being interpreted as the CSS selector `.` meta-character, so it thinks you're looking for an element with id "node1" and class "1".

The jQuery code (well, Sizzle) will let you quote that with a backslash:

```
$("#node1\\.1")
```

I'm not sure about d3.

Comment: Same solution applies to d3 as well. [See example](https://jsfiddle.net/w0gL6gu4/)